# Use external javaScript library in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 4 application and I have a javascript component that I created in a javascript file : `timeline.js`. The javascript component works well but I want to use it with angular 4. So, I put my js file in the folder `assets/js/timeline.js`.

In the file `index.html`, I call my js file with `<script src="assets/js/timeline.js"></script>` and in `app.component.ts`, I have :

```
var timeline = new Timeline("timelineVisualization")
```

So, normally, the timeline is created in the div which has `id="timelineVisualization"`.

But it doesn't work  and I have an error on the `new Timeline` : Cannot find name Timeline.

So, do you know how I can do to call the Timeline constructor from `timeline.js` ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

you simply need to do

```
 import * as Timeline from '../assets/js/timeline.js';
```

You can also do (at the top of your file) :

```
declare var Timeline: any;
```

Check also [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946104/1251861) for good practices.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works with the `declare var Timeline: any;`

Comment: If I use your suggested method, do I still need to include the path to the library in the "scripts" section of the .json file as suggested in the answer by @Srikkant Srinivasan?

Comment: Yes, you need a way to download that script from your application. The bad way would be to put it into your index.html, the good way would be to put it into your package.json

Comment: On runtime it says undefined

Comment: @MustafaKunwa have you read Srikkant Srinivasan's answer just below? The thing is propably that you also need some way to include the script into your page.

Comment: It has been resolved in another way @DeblatonJean-Philippe

Comment: this did not work for me. this solution is incomplete

Answer (score 36):

Just extending on the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945981/6657157) answer by @Deblaton Jean-Philippe and as a general good practice, it might be better to include your js or other css files as part of the build instead of putting them in your index.html.

If you are using a bundler, use something like this.

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    //Other style files
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jsplugin/dist/js/plugin.js",
    //Other script files
  ],
```

Answer (score 22):

There are 4 ways to add external javaScript libraries in Angular2+. for example: tinymce lib in npm

**1. add lib to index.html:**

```
<script src="assets/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

*.component.ts:

```
// tell TypeScript compiler that "tinymce" variable is declared somewhere in *.js
declare let tinymce: any;
```

**2. add lib to Angular.json:**

install tinymce from npm:

```
npm i tinymce
```

add *.js to angular.json:

```
"scripts": ["node-modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"]
```

*.component.ts:

```
// tell TypeScript compiler that "tinymce" variable is declared somewhere in *.js
declare let tinymce: any;
```

**3. import javaScript file in TypeScript:**

install tinymce from npm:

```
npm i tinymce
```

*.component.ts:

```
//tinymce: is a variable in 'tinymce.min.js' file => dont need "declare let tinymce"
import * as tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce.min.js'; // "js" at the end is important
```

**4.TypeScript way (I likes it):**

search typeScript header *.d.ts for tinymce at https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=tinymce

then install:

```
   npm i @types/tinymce --save-dev
```

add *tinymce.min.js* to Angular follow the 1st or 2nd way above.

*.component.ts:

```
// tinymce module at 'node-modules/@types/tinymce'
// 'node-modules/@types/tinymce'is just header, so it isn't compiled with angular
// don't need to use "declare let tinymce"
import * as tinymce from 'tinymce';
```

you can jump functions of tinymce. it is very easy to read code of tinymce lib

**after all 4 ways above:**

use tinymce with javaScript syntax. for example, the guide in tinymce lib: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/use-tinymce-classic/#

Answer (score 9):

Extending above answers a bit more

we can add the library to the project in a different way

1. Adding in HTML

   ```
   <html lang="en">
    <script src="https://nexplayer.nexplayersdk.com/latest/nexplayer.js"> 
    </script>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Adding in angular.json or .angular-cli.json

   ```
   "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jsplugin/dist/js/plugin.js",
        //Other script files
    ],
   ```
3. adding in component

   ```
   import * as Timeline from '../assets/js/timeline.js';
   ```

the second thing is declaring the name of the library

1. add in the component

   ```
    import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var library: any;
   ```
2. in type definition (*.d.ts).Create if the src/typings.d.ts does not exist, otherwise, open it, and add your package to it

   ```
   declare module 'your-library'
   ```

Comment: what do u mean by controller ?

Comment: Sorry @Mohamed . I meant component

Comment: Does this still work in Angular 9? After upgrade, we are getting `ERROR ReferenceError: [LIBRARY] is not defined`

Comment: This method will work angular 9. your issue is related to adding library file to the project.

Comment: this method is not working for me. ERR "libraryname" is NOT defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare const Timeline;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to specify the type, even if it's merely *any*? I'm thinking that **Type**Script has as it basic point assigning a type to things...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find your type definitions from :

[Definitly Typed Github Page](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyType/)

If you cannot find your library, you can write your interfaces yourself (and try to pull request it to the github page for other developers) and this interface will act like a .ts file.

Here is a start

```
declare global {
    interface Window { 
        Timeline: any
    }
}
```