# How can I import external js file in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I have a external js file named "https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/46/checkout.js" and I want to call functions using that file. How can I import that external js file in Angular4? 
I mentioned it in my angular-cli.json file as follows.

```
"scripts": [
       "https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/46/checkout.js"
   ],
```

And I also import it in my app.component.html file as follows. But it doesn't work.

```
<script src="https://testcbc.mtf.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/35/checkout.js></script>
```

Comment: refer this it will help,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945766/use-external-javascript-library-in-angular-4-application

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't helpful

Comment: Try adding script tag in `index.html`