# How to call a function in angular 5 component from javascript?

Tags: angular

I am having a javascript file say xyz.js which contain a function call on some event:

```
callToCom(x,y,z);
```

This function call is doing some piece of work.

I want to define that function in some of my angular 5 component.

Bit how can I read a function call trigger from external javascript file?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: See the below link answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945766/use-external-javascript-library-in-angular-4-application?answertab=active#tab-top