# How to add node module to Angular project if is not schematics enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, module

Cannot use ng add and npm install doesn't meet the requirements which are somewhat unclear.

How do I add an node module to angular app/project? I've installed it with npm install so what's next?

I tried adding it into  scripts array in angular.json but is caused just error "require is not defined"

Comment: adding the dependencies to package.json and running `npm install` does that not work for you?

Comment: @nkuma_12 Isn't npm install for adding dependencies - no need to add dependency but just to install one with npm. Screenshot of what?

Comment: Well, in that case you can download the `tar` or `.gzp` of the npm library you need, and keep it somewhere in the project directory and refer to it in index.html for use.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the answer to "what's next" is this:

In your `angular.json` file, add the scripts to the scripts tag:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/itsFolder/dist/js/its.js",
    // Add any other scripts here
  ],
```

This includes the script as part of the build process.

Also, check out the answers here: [Use external javaScript library in angular 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945766/use-external-javascript-library-in-angular-4-application)

Comment: This ends up in "require is not defined"

Comment: Now I tried to browserify this module and by inculding that version my browser console says  Error: Cannot find module 'http'

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
import * as md5 from 'js-md5'

ngOnInit(){
  console.log(md5(""));
}
```

Soruce: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/can-i-use-npm-packages-directly-inside-angular-2/132935/6
NOTE: I have tested this and it works. You can include any npm package and try in Angular 'ts' file, knowing what you are doing with it and how to do it.
Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Below steps might help you to start your first project in Angular. Nicely explained [here](http://musttoknow.com/how-to-setup-local-environment-for-angular-projects-with-angular-cli-example/)

```
Go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and select npm version based on your OS (Windows or Mac)
```

To check npm is installed, `run npm -v`. it will give you installed npm version.

Another commands to install latest npm

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

To check available CLI commands type this.

Now you can use below commands to Create New Angular 4 Project

```
ng new first-project
```

It will create Angular project first-app and will install required npm packages.

To start project, you can use

```
ng serve
```

To create Angular 4 Component

```
ng g component cities
```

How to create Router for The Newly Component

To make access the new component, we have to make routing for it. Open and edit src/app/app.module.ts the add this import.

```
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

imports: [  BrowserModule,  FormsModule,  HttpModule,  RouterModule.forRoot([    { path: '', redirectTo: 'newComponentName'},
    { path: 'componentname', component: ComponentName }  ])
]
```

Next, replace all tags in src/app/app.component.html with this tag.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: But how do I use a node module with this component? All forementioned is angular specific and although I want to use Angular the whole idea of node is to support modular approach: install and use it but now I missing the idea of how to install and use. I could have ever thought that it would be this hard to use a simple NPM provided module/script...

Comment: for example you want to use primeng dropdown module then you can do     
 npm i primeng --save                                                                              
      Import DropdownModule into parent module 1
  import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    DropdownModule
  ]
});  You will get same help in this tutorial in simple way [http://musttoknow.com/how-to-use-angular-4-angular-5-and-angular-6-primeng-dropdown/] ..You can try with dropdown module...

Comment: If I want to use something that has nothing to with NG (angular) but rather with this technology (javascript) and available via NPM? Currently it keeps reportin "module not found; error cannot resolve crypto, https, http, zlib. zlib_bindingins etc"

Comment: Yes..if you want to use some feature of JS tech then you find available npm for same in angular..it will get it