# How to use Javascript Library in Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a Web-Client, which is supposed to visualize Sensor data (velocity, acceleration) inside a coordinate system. To display the coordinate system i used the library `graph.js` from here https://github.com/dhuertas/graph.js , which worked perfectly fine with a classic index.html and normal javascript, but I want to use Angular7 , which does use TypeScript and Angulars Compnent app structure...
I already tried this: [Use external javaScript library in angular 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945766/use-external-javascript-library-in-angular-4-application) 
(which is basically exactly what I need)
and a couple of similar threads
but none did  work for me

What I did was the following :

the HTML of my component

```
<div style="position:relative;top:100px;left:950px" id='container' class="trajStrly"></div>
<script type="module" src="../libraries/graph.js"></script>
```

parts the component.ts:

```
import * as Graph from '../libraries/graph';
declare var Graph: any;

// ... inside the component Class...
    graph: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.graph =  new Graph({
            appendTo : "container",
            canvasWidth : 100,
            canvasHeight : 100,
            colorList : ["#666666","#666666","#00F"],
            xAxisTitle : "X",
            yAxisTitle : "Y"
        }); 
    this.draw();
  }
```

the draw function worked fine with the JavaScript and is not the probloem here. It initializes the graph with values to draw.

The Error I get is that graph.js is not a module. I already tried editing graph.js by putting `export default` in front of the definition of `Graph` inside grapf.js. 
Also already emailed the creator, but he did not answer me yet

Comment: PS: removeing `declare var Graph: any;` has the same outcome

Comment: Try removing the `script` tag from html. Also check the second answer on the link that you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you say?

> the HTML of my component

You cannot place scripts code or source references in component template as Angular will automatically sanitize the template and remove any scripts in the template html.

What you can do is

1. Add the reference it in the scripts array in **angular.json** file, or
2. add the reference in the **index.html** file
3. write a code to **manually inject the script in the DOM**

**Edit:**
Steps:

1. Create Assets folder an your angular application is it doesn't already exists.
2. Copy-paste your js file there.
3. Add the js file path in the scripts array in `angular.json` file, make sure you point to the correct file.

Your component code will be like following

```
declare var Graph: any;
graph: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.graph =  new Graph({
        appendTo : "container",
        canvasWidth : 100,
        canvasHeight : 100,
        colorList : ["#666666","#666666","#00F"],
        xAxisTitle : "X",
        yAxisTitle : "Y"
    }); 
    this.draw();
}
```

Notice: no need to add this line in your component.ts `import * as Graph from '../libraries/graph';`

Comment: thank you very much. Turns out I only had to restart VS Code, but this is really the answer I have been looking for