# Angular library for drawing lines between objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package, angular7

I am looking for a package to include in my angular project like this:
https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/

I've read that is quite a hassle to import vanilla javascript libraries into a typescript project so i was wondering if somebody knows an equivelant of this library as a package for angular. I've searched online but so far no luck.

Comment: You should have no problem importing vanilla javascript libs into typescript. All javascript is valid typescript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402225/how-to-use-javascript-library-in-angular-component i am reading this now. I've imported the folder into my assets folder and imported it in the angular.json in the scripts array as  "src/assets/scripts/anseki-leader-line-2cd19cd/leader-line.min.js" But how can i use it now? tried some stuff but i think i declare it wrong

Comment: [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) is another library worth taking a look at too.

Comment: looks interesting! it's in my bookmarks now! For now i can see ;/*! LeaderLine v1.0.5 (c) anseki https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/ */ in my scripts.js so it is included. How do i declare it so i can use it in my typescript file? So far no luck

Comment: Have you tried installing the npm package and including it as you usually would?

Comment: i've added it manually, stupid me. Makes more sense to do it via the cli. Will try that

Comment: Allright i've installed it via npm, i am a little bit lost now on how to include it in my typescript can't get it work. So far i've got this

import { LeaderLine } from 'node_modules/leader-line/leader-line.min.js';

Not sure if it is the right way and how to work with it now

Answer (score 9):

Step 1: Install LeaderLine

```
npm i leader-line --save
```

Step 2: Include it in angular.json

```
 "scripts": [
               "./node_modules/leader-line/leader-line.min.js"
            ],
```

Step 3: Import leader-line, declare LeaderLine and inject document

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common";
import 'leader-line';
declare let LeaderLine: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<div id="d1">div 1</div><div style="height:500px"><!-- JUST SOME SPACE --></div><div id="d2"> Connect me</div>',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    new LeaderLine(
      this.document.getElementById('d1'),
      this.document.getElementById('d2')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello, I followed above-mentioned steps, However, i  m getting

TicketAssociatedeviceEditComponent.html:1 ERROR ReferenceError: LeaderLine is not defined

Please let me know what went wrong. I'll give you a up vote

Comment: Its hard to know it without example. There is several possible problems that I can think of:
- installation of library failed
-import is not correct (in angular.js or in ts file, check paths)
- declaration is not on correct position (shout be outside class body)
My bet is that path to library is not correct.

Comment: @TomislavTuralija. I just followed the steps. But am unable reproduce the line. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @PrashanthDamam can you be more precise? Do you have github project to share?

Comment: [Error demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ms8h65?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: if you have issues still, run npm install.

Comment: if the DOM elements are getting added dynamically then LeaderLine always fails as document.getElementById always returns null, haven't been able to make it work in such situation

Answer (score 1):

Please restart ,i.e:
 run `ng serve --open`, again and everything will run fine :)