# How to use external js lib into angular component test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component that uses an external js library: leader-line.
When I try to test that component, it always throws an error that function for the external library is not defined.

`component file`

```
declare var LeaderLine: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flow-line',
  templateUrl: './flow-line.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flow-line.component.css']
})
export class FlowLineComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() public flowPathConfig: any = new Array();
  public myLines: any = new Array();
  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (let config of this.flowPathConfig) {
      if (document.getElementById(config.fromStep) && document.getElementById(config.toStep)) {
        this.myLines.push(new LeaderLine(
          document.getElementById(config.fromStep),
          document.getElementById(config.toStep)
        ));
      }
    }
  }
```

spec file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FlowLineComponent } from './flow-line.component';
import { FundamentalNgxModule } from 'fundamental-ngx';


describe('FlowLineComponent', () => {
  let component: FlowLineComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FlowLineComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FlowLineComponent],
      imports: [FundamentalNgxModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FlowLineComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('it should draw line with pathConfig', () => {
    component.flowPathConfig = [{ fromStep: '1', toStep: '2' }];
    let el1 = document.createElement('div');
    el1.setAttribute('id', '1');
    let el2 = document.createElement('div');
    el2.setAttribute('id', '2');
    document.body.appendChild(el1);
    document.body.appendChild(el2);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    expect(component.myLines.length).toEqual(0);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Following is the error trace. That shows reference error. 
PS: I have included the leader-line library using the following post: [Use external javaScript library in angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945766/use-external-javascript-library-in-angular-application)

```
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) FlowLineComponent it should draw line with pathConfig FAILED
        ReferenceError: LeaderLine is not defined
            at <Jasmine>
            at FlowLineComponent.LeaderLine [as ngAfterViewInit] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/flow/flow-line/flow-line.component.ts:34:43)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/flow/flow-line/flow-line.component.spec.ts:45:15)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)
            at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:1)
            at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:561:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:576:1)
            at <Jasmine>
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 13 of 16 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 3.274 secs)
HeadlessChrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) FlowLineComponent it should draw line with pathConfig FAILED
        ReferenceError: LeaderLine is not defined
            at <Jasmine>
            at FlowLineComponent.LeaderLine [as ngAfterViewInit] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/flow/flow-line/flow-line.component.ts:34:43)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/flow/flow-line/flow-line.component.spec.ts:45:15)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)
            at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:1)
            at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:561:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:576:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to import the lib like this :

```
import * as LeaderLine from 'leader-line';
```

instead of the var declaration. Is it only the tests that doesn't work or when you run your app it throws the error as well ?

Comment: I have added external js into  `angular.json` it works fine in runtime. I throw an error in a test only. If I do import statement in spec file as you mentioned, it throws `EsLint error` because I do not call LeaderLine explicitly in a test.

Answer (score 1):

I inject the methods in the component by using the function declaration way.

```
declare function A();
```

A way to test only the component's methods, and ignore all the imported ones from the external js file.
You can create a mock/<external.js> file, that will replace the origin on testing mode. You have to add it also into the angular.json file in test configuration.

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/env.js"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/sass/intracom-light.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/mock/js/maps.js"
        ]
      }
    },
```

Replace the body of the calling methods to set up the testing behavior.