# Use external JavaScript library in Angular 8 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and i want to develop a funnel-graph. i like the [funnel-graph-js](https://github.com/greghub/funnel-graph-js) library. i tried a lot but haven't succeed.

here is my `funnel-graph-directive.ts`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

// import * as graph from '../../../assets/js/funnel-graph.js';
import * as graph from 'funnel-graph-js/dist/js/funnel-graph.js';
var graph = new FunnelGraph({
  container: '.funnel',
  gradientDirection: 'horizontal',
  data: {
    labels: ['Impressions', 'Add To Cart', 'Buy'],
    subLabels: ['Direct', 'Social Media', 'Ads'],
    colors: [
      ['#FFB178', '#FF78B1', '#FF3C8E'],
      ['#A0BBFF', '#EC77FF'],
      ['#A0F9FF', '#7795FF']
    ],
    values: [
      [3500, 2500, 6500],
      [3300, 1400, 1000],
      [600, 200, 130]
    ]
  },
  displayPercent: true,
  direction: 'horizontal'
});

graph.draw();
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFunnelGraph]'
})
export class FunnelGraphDirective {
  style: any;
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

I have added these lines in my `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "./node_modules/funnel-graph-js/dist/css/main.css",
  "./node_modules/funnel-graph-js/dist/css/theme.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/funnel-graph-js/dist/js/funnel-graph.js"
]
```

Here is the error i am getting
[image]

Comment: In your HTML there should be an element with a "funnel" class. Are you sure this element exists in your code?

Comment: @Drago96 initially, i hadn't put the element with a `funnel` class but yes your comment was helpful. i made a `service` and that's how i solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by creating `service` instead of using `directive` approach.

- First i generated a service called `dynamic-script-loader-service` in
  my `dashboard` module.

> dynamic-service-loader.service.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}

export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
  { name: 'chartjs', src: 'https://unpkg.com/funnel-graph-js@1.3.9/dist/js/funnel-graph.min.js' },
];

declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService {

  private scripts: any = {};

  constructor() {
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
      this.scripts[script.name] = {
        loaded: false,
        src: script.src
      };
    });
  }

  load(...scripts: string[]) {
    const promises: any[] = [];
    scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }

  loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.scripts[name].loaded) {
        //load script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
        if (script.readyState) {  //IE
          script.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
              script.onreadystatechange = null;
              this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
              resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
            }
          };
        } else {  //Others
          script.onload = () => {
            this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
            resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
          };
        }
        script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({ script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded' });
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      } else {
        resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded' });
      }
    });
  }

}
```

> dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService } from '../dynamic-script-loader-service.service';
import * as FunnelGraph from 'funnel-graph-js';

function dashboardFunnel() {
  const graph = new FunnelGraph({
    container: '.funnel',
    // gradientDirection: 'horizontal',
    data: {
      labels: ['Label 7', 'Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5', 'Label 6'],
      colors: ['#00A8FF', '#00A8FF', '#00A8FF', '#00A8FF', '#00A8FF', '#00A8FF', '#00A8FF'],
      // color: '#00A8FF',
      values: [12000, 11000, 10000, 9000, 8000, 7000, 6000]
    },
    displayPercent: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
  });

  graph.draw();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dynamicScriptLoader: DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScripts();
    dashboardFunnel();
  }

  private loadScripts() {
    // You can load multiple scripts by just providing the key as argument into load method of the service
    this.dynamicScriptLoader.load('chartjs', 'random-num').then(data => {
      // Script Loaded Successfully
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

}
```

> added `providers` in my `dashboard.module.ts`

```
providers: [DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService],
```

> added `css` in my `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/funnel-graph-js/dist/css/main.css",
              "./node_modules/funnel-graph-js/dist/css/theme.css"
            ],
```

added `div` with class `funnel` in `dashboard.component.html`

```
<div class="funnel"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you linked the javascript file in the html, it will work fine.

**EDIT:**

A better way to include an addition javascript file is to put it into the "scripts" section in the *angular.json* file. You can also add

```
declare const FunnelGraph: any
```

in order to compile without errors. This has been taken from [an answer to a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945766/use-external-javascript-library-in-angular-application) and [this guide](https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular). Remember to include the css files in that json too!

**EDIT END**

You get that error because the code tries to look for an HTML element with a class named "funnel", but cannot find it. Since this is a directive, it would be better if it was a little more generalized.

First of all, you should move your graph-generating code inside the constructor, since that's were the directive logic resides. To better generalize this directive, it would be best if you gave a unique id to that element and change the code accordingly. This is how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="funnel-graph-1" appFunnelGraph></div>
```

JS:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

// It should be fine to just import this in the html with a script tag
// import * as graph from 'funnel-graph-js/dist/js/funnel-graph.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFunnelGraph]'
})
export class FunnelGraphDirective {
  style: any;
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

    var graph = new FunnelGraph({
      // Generalize the container selector with the element id
      container: '#' + el.nativeElement.id,
      gradientDirection: 'horizontal',
      data: {
        labels: ['Impressions', 'Add To Cart', 'Buy'],
        subLabels: ['Direct', 'Social Media', 'Ads'],
        colors: [
          ['#FFB178', '#FF78B1', '#FF3C8E'],
          ['#A0BBFF', '#EC77FF'],
          ['#A0F9FF', '#7795FF']
        ],
        values: [
          [3500, 2500, 6500],
          [3300, 1400, 1000],
          [600, 200, 130]
        ]
      },
      displayPercent: true,
      direction: 'horizontal'
    });

    graph.draw();
  }
}
```

Comment: " this may generate a typescript error" ... That's why we should at least define an interface :) But all in all, that's my preferred way and more natural and less cumbersome than constructing a service.

Comment: yes you are right. `directive` approach is less cumbersome than `service`. thanks for answering. Upvote.

Comment: @ak.leimrey You're right, I maybe went a little easy on that :) I updated the answer with some usefult tips found online (tested and working)